# Creating Welcome Email in Automation Studio

Tags: email, automationstudio

Fairly new to SFMC, I don't have access to Journey Builder and want to send a 'Welcome Email' to a DE that captures subs from a signup form.  How do I send out an every hour, recurring email to those new subs throughout the day, without sending to someone who has already received?  Not sure how to override that DE in automation studio after someone has been sent the Welcome Email/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question you need a way to exclude subscribers after they have received the welcome email. I am not sure if Automation Studio is the best option and there is probably a smarter solution. Anyway: Start by creating 2 more DEs, one for storing the hourly sends (Hourly sends DE) and one for logging all sends (Logging DE). Create 3 activities and put in an automation and schedule the automation to run every hour.

1. SQL Activity - Create a SQL activity to query the Capture DE (where you have your new subscribers) and exclude all subscribers that have received the welcome email (are in the Logging DE). Store the result in the Hourly Send DE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560471/how-to-exclude-rows-that-dont-join-with-another-table
2. Send Email Activity – Use the Hourly Send DE to send the Welcome Emails.
3. SQL Activity – Store subscribers that have received the Welcome Email in the Logging DE, either by querying the send log or by using the Hourly Send DE.

If you are not comfortable with SQL, you could also consider:

Welcome emails:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_welcome_email.htm&type=5

Triggered emails:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_triggered_emails.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot.  Yea, I have a sign-up list being pulled in to a DE. 
 I want to send those new names a Welcome Email that I want recurring every hour the day they sign up.  I wanted to make sure that the names previously sent the Welcome Email don't get it again.  Unfortunately, the BU I'm using doesn't have Journey Builder active so I can't use that.  If there is another way I'd gladly try.